# jSoup - remove particular style attributes

Tags: java, jsoup

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

INPUT:

```
<span style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Lucida Sans','sans-serif'; COLOR: #003572; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; 
mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri; mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-fareast-language: EN-US; 
mso-bidi-language: AR-SA; mso-fareast-theme-font: minor-latin">Dr. Who is 
<u>usually</u> available for consultations Mon - Thurs afternoons and Friday 9a-
12p at 555-1212. </span>
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

> <span style="COLOR: #003572; FONT-SIZE: 9pt;">Dr. Who is
>   <u>usually</u> available for consultations Mon - Thurs
>   afternoons and Friday 9a-12p at 555-1212. </span>

MY CODE SO FAR:

> //cleans the HTML within the Week Long note before writing to the DB
>
> ```
>   Whitelist wl = new Whitelist();         
>   wl = Whitelist.simpleText();
>   wl.addTags("br");
>   wl.addTags("p");
>   wl.addTags("span");
>   wl.addAttributes(":all","style");
>   Document doc = 
>               Jsoup.parse(
>                "<html><head></head><body>"+ds.getWeeklongNote()+"</body></html>");
>   Elements e = doc.select("*");
>   for (Element el : e){
>       for (Attribute attr : el.attributes()){
>           if (attr.getKey().equals("span")){
>               String newValue = "";
>               String s = attr.getValue();
>               String[] values = s.split(";");
>               for (String value : values){
>                   if (value.startsWith("COLOR")||value.startsWith("FONT-SIZE")){
>                       newValue += attr.getKey()+"="+attr.getValue()+";";
>                   }
>               }
>               attr.setValue(newValue);
>           }
>       }
>   }
>
>   doc.html(e.outerHtml());
>   ds.setWeekLongNote(Jsoup.clean(doc.body().outerHtml(), wl));
> ```

Comment: `Jsoup.parse("<html<` - What's with the broken `<html>` tag?

Comment: Nice catch, but not quite what I was looking for. Since STYLE is an attribute that essentially accepts an array as its value, is there a **better way** to edit the contents of a STYLE tag than what I am working on above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
  Elements e = doc.getElementsByTag("body");            
  Log.i("Span element: "+e.get(0).nodeName(), ""+e.get(0).nodeName());
  e = e.get(0).getElementsByTag("span");
  Attributes styleAtt = e.get(0).attributes();
  Attribute a = styleAtt.asList().get(0);           
  if(a.getKey().equals("style")){
     String[] items = a.getValue().trim().split(";");
     String newValue = "";
     for(String item: items){

         if(item.contains("COLOR:")||item.contains("FONT-SIZE:")){
             Log.i("Style Item: ", ""+item);
             newValue = newValue.concat(item).concat(";");
         }
     }
     a.setValue(newValue);
     Log.i("New Atrrbute: ",""+newValue);                    
  }

  Log.i("FINAL HTML: ",""+e.outerHtml()); 

  doc.html(e.outerHtml());
    }
```

Output:

`08-17 18:28:07.692: I/FINAL HTML:(8148): <span style=" COLOR: #003572; FONT-SIZE: 9pt;">Dr. Who is <u>usually</u> available for consultations Mon - Thurs afternoons and Friday 9a- 12p at 555-1212. </span>`

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one span element you can use this code snippet:

```
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Vector<String> allowedItems = new Vector<String>();
    allowedItems.add("color");
    allowedItems.add("font-size");

    Elements e = document.getElementsByTag("span");
    for (Element element : e) {
        String[] styles = element.attr("style").split(";");
        Vector<String> filteredItems = new Vector<String>();
        for (String item : styles) {
            String key = (item.split(":"))[0].trim().toLowerCase();
            if ( allowedItems.contains(key) ){
                filteredItems.add(item);
            }
        }
        if( filteredItems.size() == 0 ){
            element.removeAttr("style");        
        }else{
            element.attr("style",StringUtils.join(filteredItems, ";"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//remove style attribute
    Elements elms = doc.select("*").not("img");
    for (Element e : elms) {
        String attr = e.attr("style");
        if(!"".equals(attr) || null!=attr){
            e.attr("style", "");
        }
    }
```

Comment: An explanation of your approach would be better received than just a lump of code. Would you mind telling us a bit more about what you're doing here?

Comment: This removes all the style text after a search through elements. So for your case you have escape styles attributes you don't want inside that loop.